# C# calling a method from inner class that has reference to outerclass

Tags: c#

I have a class called Foo, it has an inner class Inner. The Inner class has reference to outer class's field.

```
public class Foo
{
    int foo = 2;

    public class Inner
    {
        Foo f;
        public Inner(Foo f)
        {
            f=f;
        }

        public override String ToString()
        {
            return "Inner[foo="+f.foo+"]" ;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my program.

```
public class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {    
      Foo foo=new Foo();
      Foo.Inner inner=new Foo.Inner(foo);
      Console.WriteLine(inner.ToString());
   }
}
```

There is no problem to compile it, but it fails when I run it.
It gives me an exception

> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.   at Foo.Inner.ToString()

What is going on here?

Comment: Why do you want to create a nested class? Why can't it be two independent classes with a readonly property of type `Inner` in `Foo`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem:**

Your problem is in doing `f = f`.  It is not doing anything productive. This line does not update the `Inner` field `f` and it remains unassigned or `null`. So when you do `Console.WriteLine(inner.ToString());`, it throws error at `"Inner[foo=" + f.foo + "]"`

Also VS shows a warning

[image]

**Solution:** 
1. Change constructor variable to something else. Like this

```
Foo f;
public Inner(Foo f1)
{
    f = f1;
}
```

OR 

2. Add `this` to distinguish between variables.

```
Foo f;
public Inner(Foo f)
{
    this.f = f;
}
```

Comment: I wonder whether a "release" compilation would cut the whole operation, avoiding the exception...a nice test to do!

Comment: @MarioVernari no it wont, if it cut it then the code won't work!

Comment: @MarioVernari: It still throws exception in Release mode even though warning is ignored but this line still remains `return "Inner[foo=" + f.foo + "]";`.

Answer (score 3):

To fix the problem you can chnage the following

`f=f;`

to

`this.f = f;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to assgined a Foo obejct like

```
        Foo f;
        public Inner(Foo _f)
        {
            f = _f;
        }
```